# Can't create Local Network Gateway in Azure

Tags: azure

When trying to create a new Local Network Gateway I'm getting an error for the submission saying 'This offer is not available for subscriptions from Microsoft Azure Cloud Solution Providers'.

My account is 'owner' of the subscription (so it has Microsoft.Network/LocalNetworkGateways create / write permissions) and the subscription itself has Microsoft.Network resource provider already registered (I created successfully vNet and a vNet Gateway).

No idea if missing something from subscription or some setting for CSP we work with? Subscription uses 'pay as you go' plan.

Any hints? TIA

Comment: The error message is telling you the problem. The type of account you're using isn't eligible to create the type of resource you want to create.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get it. How can I enable a resource type (local network gateway) in a subscription? As far as I know a resource is not available because of few reasons: 1. not available in my region (not the case for this case), 2. not registered as resource provider (this is part of MS.Network which is registered as resource provider), 3. because of permissions (my account is owner of subscription), 4. restricted policies (not the case), 5. possible other scenarios. Of course I google it and couldn't find any good explanation, based on error message. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I also contacted MS Q&A and they provided some workarounds (1st one worked for me), acknowledging the issue.

Thank you for reaching out. I just went through similar issues using our internal tooling and found that below work-arounds worked for the customer. Can you try the steps mentioned below and see if that fixes the issue.

1. Do a "Hard Refresh" (F5) on the page and see if that fixes the issue. (This helped resolve the issue for most of the customers.)
2. Create using the following URL: https://link.edgepilot.com/s/b7b99a1c/OHp2IQfsYESVtpZFaOHItA?u=https://portal.azure.com/?feature.canmodifystamps=true%26Microsoft_Azure_HybridNetworking=flight1%23home
3. Create using PowerShell: Connect your on-premises network to an Azure VNet: [Site-to-Site VPN: PowerShellAzure VPN Gateway | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-create-site-to-site-rm-powershell#2-create-the-local-network-gateway)

Looks like this is a known issue and the team is currently working on fixing it.